# Ember : sortBy or Ember.computed.sort

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting, ember.js

I saw an example of Ember sortBy somewhere which goes like:

```
model.sortBy("time").reverse().sortBy("place")
```

It was working, but am not sure if this is a good way to do that. Would the below a better fit for this. If yes, why.

```
sortOptions: ['time:desc','place']
Ember.computed.sort('model',sortOptions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model.sortBy("time").reverse().sortBy("place")
```

Will sort the array `model` one time.

```
Ember.computed.sort('model',sortOptions)
```

Will recompute its value every time `model` or its properties change.
So what you should use depends on what you need. I don't think there's a significant difference in performance of the sort itself.

Comment: All right, thanks for the help. In this case, its just sorting once, so i guess should be fine.

Comment: I have another related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718700/ember-computed-sort , could you please help on that as well.

Comment: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/computed-sort-10-times-slower-than-sortby/12467 claims that Ember.computed.sort isn't fast in comparison to sortBy. so defining a plain ember computed property and sorting within that using sortBy is also an option worth considering.