# Ember - computed sort

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, ember.js

I am using the below code for sorting a list.

```
sortOptions: ['amount:desc','place']
Ember.computed.sort('model',sortOptions)
```

The key "amount" is basically a number, but in JSON "model", its coming as a string. So, when I ran this code, it wasn't sorting by amount, but when I modified the JSON to convert that amount string to amount number, that worked. 
Is this correct behavior of Ember computed sort?

Comment: sort function is working correctly. it's your job to provide proper data

Comment: cool..just wanted to confirm that..thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom function with the `Ember.computed.sort` which can solve your problem

I believe you get string as amount from JSON and you want to sort it as descending order.

```
// using a custom sort function
Ember.computed.sort('model', function(a, b){
  if (a.amount > b.amount) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.amount < b.amount) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
})
```